# JS | jQuery - on scroll event on every item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to call a function when the client scrolls on any item on the page.

I know I can do as followed:

`$(window).scroll(callback)`

But if there are other elements that have `overflow: scroll;` the callback will not be called.

So how do I hook the callback to any scroll event?

Comment: As far as I know you'll have to individually attach scroll watchers to each scrollable element.

Answer (score 1):

However, you must insert a function that indicates which elements or what type of effects to insert. For example you could put:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     $( "p" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Yea I know that I have to put something inside tha callback but how do I call the callback on any element scroll